# ambigious functions in c++

Tags: c++, overloading

I would like to know why these declarations won't work(are not compatible)

```
void f(int); //p1
void f(const int);//p2
void f(int &);//p3
void f(const int &);//p4
```

If I understood well, the compiler won't find a difference between (int &) and (const int &)
and if I write f(12) it won't be able to choose between the two first declarations..
Am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

p3 and p4 are perfectly unambiguous and distinguishable, p1 and p2 are not. (And of course p1/p2 are distinguishable from p3 and p4.)

The reason is that top-level `const` on a value parameter is not detectable and infact useless on a declaration. You can for example do the following:

```
void foo(int x); // declaration
// ...
void foo(const int x){
  // definition/implementation
}
```

The `const` here is an implementation detail that's not important for the caller, since you make a copy anyways. That copy is also the reason why it's not distinguishable from just `int`, from the callers side it's *exactly the same*.

Note that `const int& r` does not have a top-level `const`, it's the reference that refers to a constant integer (references are always constant). For pointers, which may be changed if not declared `const`, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1143262/500104) for where to put `const`.