# ambigious definitions in c++

Tags: c++, call, ambiguous

I can't find out why calls of f are ambigiuous :/ I know that the three declarations are ok but in this case this isn't working..

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void f(int);
void f(int &);
void f(const int &);

void f(int a);

void f(int &a);

   void f(const int &a);


int main()
{
    int i=1;
    const int ic=2;
    int &ri=i;
    const int & rc=ic;

    f(i);
    f(ic);
    f(ri);
    f(rc);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that the three declarations are ok

How? All arguments are convertible to `int`. The ambiguity is clear.

Do you think `int x = rc;` won't compile?

I think your confusion stems from `void f(int);`. Since the parameter is passed **by value**, anything that can be copied in a new `int` matches this overload.

Comment: I actually think the confusion came from the answer to this question that makes it look like those three are unambiguous: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122294/ambigious-functions-in-c